# MATLAB: compiled standalone application with several input files by drag'n'drop

Tags: matlab, drag-and-drop

I use MATLAB 2014a (or newer) on Windows 7 and use an app that I have compiled using the MATLAB compiler. This app uses the filename as one input parameter and calculates some things. I can also drag'n'drop files onto the app and it does its job.

My question is how to drag'n'drop **several files** onto the app. I get the error "too many input argument" but cannot see how the several filenames are passed to the app since I get the error beforce the app source code is executed where I could debug the input parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work with http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html as input parameters of the wrapper for the standalone app.